# Type 'Popup | null' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Popup> | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet to display a map and I want to create a marker wherever the user clicks. The marker should have a popup open by default and this is where I am having trouble.

`/src/components/mapcontainer/popup.component.tsx:`

```
import { Map, Popup as LeafletPopup } from "leaflet";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import "./popup.style.scss";

type Props = {
  map: Map;
};
const Popmenu = ({ map }: Props) => {
  const popupRef = useRef<LeafletPopup>(null);

  popupRef.current && map.openPopup(popupRef.current);

  return (
    <Popup ref={popupRef.current}>
      <div className="popup">
        <button> Set as start</button>
        <button> Set as destination</button>
      </div>
    </Popup>
  );
};

export default Popmenu;
```

Typescript will throw and error at this line `<Popup ref={popupRef.current}>` saying:

```
TS2322: Type 'Popup | null' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Popup> | undefined'.
  Type 'Popup' is not assignable to type 'Ref<Popup> | undefined'.
    13 |
    14 |   return (
  > 15 |     <Popup ref={popupRef.current}>
       |            ^^^
```

**Question**: How can I create a ref to a Popup?

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Hasan-aga/bike-router/draft/agitated-bessie?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fmapcontainer%2Fpopup.component.tsx

Here is my package.json (TLDR I have installed @types/leaflet@1.9.0):

```
{
  "name": "bike-router",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `ref` directly `<Popup ref={popupRef}>`

Comment: oh man! how did I miss that?! thanks for the answer @bbbbbbbboat